# ng-switch not working with nested ng-repeat for table

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I am getting error while rendering table based on provided columns definitions and row data (2 different JSON objects) using nested 'ng-repeat' and `ng-switch` directives:

Is there any way to use 'ng-repeat' and `ng-switch` for rendering table cells without using wrapper elements.

```javascript
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngSwitch', required by directive 'ngSwitchWhen', can't be found!
```

**Here is my table template**

```markup
<table id={{metaData.id}} name="{{metaData.name}}" class="{{metaData.classes}}">
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in data">
        <td ng-repeat="col in metaData.columns" ng-switch on="col.type"
        ng-switch-when="index"> {{record.$index + 1}} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Work around I made for time being**

I am using `ng-if` to render table `cell` and `rows` dynamically in following way:

```
<table id={{metaData.id}} name="{{metaData.name}}" class="{{metaData.classes}} vk-table" >
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="record in data | orderBy : sortBy : reverse">
                <td ng-repeat-start="col in metaData.columns" ng-if="col.type == 'index'"> {{$parent.$parent.$index + 1}}. </td>
                <td ng-if="col.type =='name'">{{record.name = [record.fname, record.mname, record.lname].join(' ') }}</td>
                <td ng-if="col.type =='date'">{{record[col.dataKey] = toDate(record[col.dataKey]) | date : 'mediumDate'}}</td>
                <td ng-if="col.type =='inMobile'">
                    <a href="tel:{{record[col.dataKey]}}">{{record[col.dataKey]}}</a>
                </td>
                <td ng-if="col.type =='email'">
                    <a href="mailto:{{record[col.dataKey]}}">{{record[col.dataKey]}}</a>

                </td>
                <td ng-if="col.type =='gender'">{{record[col.dataKey] == 'm' ? 'Male' : 'Female'}}</td>
                <td ng-if="col.type =='place'">{{record[col.dataKey].name}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat-end ng-if="!col.type">{{record[col.dataKey]}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How can I achieve same output using `ng-switch` without using additional elements?

Comment: I just do not want to use additional wrapper elements.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly are you trying to achieve. Why are you using ng-switch-when in the first place?

Comment: @GiladBeeri : I updated the question under **Work around I made for time being** section. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: see my revised answer @Vikram

Answer (score 0):

The ng-switch-when directive should be applied on a child element of the element where the ng-switch directive is applied. In your case, you applied them on the same element.

Try (inside tbody)

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in data | orderBy : sortBy : reverse">
    <td ng-repeat="col in metaData.columns">
        <div ng-switch on="col.type">
            <div ng-switch-when="index"> 
                {{record.$index + 1}}
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="name"> 
                {{record.name = [record.fname, record.mname, record.lname].join(' ') }}
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="date"> 
                {{record[col.dataKey] = toDate(record[col.dataKey]) | date : 'mediumDate'}}
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="inMobile"> 
                <a href="tel:{{record[col.dataKey]}}">{{record[col.dataKey]}}</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="email"> 
                <a href="mailto:{{record[col.dataKey]}}">{{record[col.dataKey]}}</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="gender"> 
                {{record[col.dataKey] == 'm' ? 'Male' : 'Female'}}
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="place"> 
                {{record[col.dataKey].name}}
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default> 
                {{record[col.dataKey]}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks fr ur answer. I would like to avoid additional markup.

Comment: Which additional markup? the 2 layers of div elements? Note that ngSwitchWhen must be a child of ngSwitch, so you need to add at least one layer. Maybe putting the ngSwitch as an attribute of the td will work.

Comment: `ng-switch` as attribute not working for my use-case. I am working on another work around and soon post answer for this scenario. Thanks for your time.